# Fire google amp-analytics event in an amp page when amp-form submit success

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics, amp-form

I am trying to fire an event after submit success in AMP.

At the moment I use dataLayer.push() and sending: category, action and label.

How do i fire the success event with the example from this documentation https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/#analytics-triggers

This the code form the documentation:

```
<amp-analytics>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "requests": {
        "event": "https://www.example.com/analytics/event?eid=${eventId}",
        "searchEvent": "https://www.example.com/analytics/search?formId=${formId}&query=${formFields[query]}"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "formSubmit": {
          "on": "amp-form-submit",
          "request": "searchEvent"
        },
        "formSubmitSuccess": {
          "on": "amp-form-submit-success",
          "request": "event",
          "vars": {
            "eventId": "form-submit-success"
          }
        },
        "formSubmitError": {
          "on": "amp-form-submit-error",
          "request": "event",
          "vars": {
            "eventId": "form-submit-error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The [selector](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-analytics/#element-selector) is missing - AMP has to know about which form element this is
2. Additional data can be passed as `vars`. E.g. for Google Analytics, it's `event_label`, `event_name`, and `event_category`. More on [AMP & GA integration here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/).

```
…
"formSubmit": {
  "on": "amp-form-submit-success",
  "selector": "form",
  "request": "event",
  "vars": {
    "event_label": "Label 1"
  }
},
…
```